# Modifying a function to convert text URLs to links and limit name

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So I have this function to convert text URLs to links. What do I need to add to `preg_replace`, to limit a long URL, currently it displays domain only, I would like to add a **4th attribute** to this, that **shows limit from full URL, limits the URL**, I have no idea how to do this.  This function is tested and works very well this is why I want to keep using it, how to I add this extra snippet for 4th attribute.

```
function autolink($str, $attributes=array()) {
    $attrs = '';
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute => $value) {
        $attrs .= " {$attribute}=\"{$value}\"";
    }
    $str = ' ' . $str;
    $str = preg_replace(
        '|([\w\d]*)\s(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i',
        '$1 <a href="$2"'.$attrs.' title="$2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">$3</a>',
        $str
    );
    return $str;
}
```

Can someone please help me out.

INPUT:

```
$cont=autolink("https://www.example.com/test.php?ss=a https://www.example.com/2 https://www.exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaample.com/3");
```

Output current:

```
   <a href="https://www.example.com/test.php?ss=a" title="https://www.example.com/test.php?ss=a" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">www.example.com</a> <a href="https://www.example.com/2" title="https://www.example.com/2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">www.example.com</a> <a href="https://www.exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaample.com/3" title="https://www.exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaample.com/3" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">www.exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaample.com</a>
```

WANTED output:

```
   <a href="https://www.example.com/test.php?ss=a" title="https://www.example.com/test.php?ss=a" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">www.example.com/test...</a> <a href="https://www.example.com/2" title="https://www.example.com/2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">www.example.com/2</a> <a href="https://www.exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaample.com/3" title="https://www.exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaample.com/3" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">www.exxxxxxxxxxxxx.....</a>
```

I should be able to limit the URL name to like 40 chars. Anyways the third attribute is not needed and would be modified, not returning the domain, but the real name of URL limited to 40 chars.

Comment: Your current regex can be written as `'|(\w*)\s(https?://([\w.-]+\.[\w.]{2,6})[^][\s<>]*/?)|i'` - it will match the same texts. Please provide some input and expected output.

Comment: Example input would be http://www.example.com/test.php?f=test  and output would be   www.example.com/test.p... Thank you

Comment: It is still unclear: what the attribute should be? Should it really be some "shortname="http://siite.com/gh..." or the `$3` must be the shortened URL? What are the shortening requirements?

Comment: Wound the edit button, I hope it's clear now.

Comment: take a look at this https://regex101.com/r/vT2lF3/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's final: answer is `*preg_replace_callback*`and this is the best regex, used here, best way to make text URL to HTML link, easy to modify.

```
function autolink($textOriginal)
    {
        $textOriginal=" $textOriginal";
        $urlPattern = '|([\w]*)\s(https?://([\w.-]+\.[\w.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i';
        $textNew    = preg_replace_callback($urlPattern, "replaceLinkParts", $textOriginal);

        return $textNew;
    }

    function replaceLinkParts($matches)
    {
 $thefullurl=''.$matches[2].'';
  $whatisthis=''.$matches[1].'';

 //////////
    $myDomainx = parse_url("$thefullurl");
     $simpleurl="" . $myDomainx["host"] . "";
         $simpleurlp = "" . $myDomainx["path"] . "";
         if ($simpleurlp == "/") { 
          $simpleurlp = "";
          }
         $newurl="$simpleurl$simpleurlp";
         ////////////////
         $lastpart= "";

         $limichars="30";        
$limitlast="10";
$calcit=$limichars-$limitlast;
$nmre=strlen($newurl);
if ($nmre > $limichars) { 
$lastpart=$nmre - $limitlast;
$lastpart= substr($newurl, $lastpart, $limitlast);

$newurl= substr($newurl, 0, $calcit);
$newurl= ''.$newurl.'...';
  } 
  ////////////
  $retthis=''.$whatisthis.' <a target="_blank" title="'.$thefullurl.'" rel="nofollow" href="'.$thefullurl.'">'.$newurl.''.$lastpart.'</a>';

        return $retthis;
    }
```

Outputs HTML link: www.example.com...ifverylongurl

Comment: As I said, there is no point using `[\w\d]`, it is the same as writing `\w`. No point escaping the dot inside the character class, `[\.]` = `[.]`.

Comment: changed as you suggested